# Help me with my select query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have this table in sql server 2005:

```
id   student active
1   Bob     1
3   Rob     0
5   Steve   1
7   John    1
8   Mark    0
10   Dave    0
16   Nick    1
```

My select query returns an active student by a given id. 
But I also want to return the ids of prev and next student who are active. If no prev, it will be 0 or null. Same for next.

Example: for id=5, my select would return

```
id    student    prev_id    next_id
5     steve       1          7
```

Example: for id=7, my select would return

```
id    student    prev_id    next_id
7     John       5          16
```

Example: for id=16, my select would return

```
id    student    prev_id    next_id
16    Nick       7          0
```

How do I write this select query?

I have query but I just can't get the prev id correctly. It always returns the first active id.

Thanks

**EDIT:
Here is the query I have right now.**

```
select id, student, 
(select top 1 id from test where id<7 and active=1) as prev,
(select top 1 id from test where id>7 and active=1) as next 
from test where id=7--I used 7 just as an example. it will be a parameter
```

Comment: i can think of some pretty nasty correlated subqueries that will get you what you want, but whats the reason for this requirement?  perhaps there is a different way to meet this requirement.

Comment: select id, student, 
(select top 1 id from test where id<7 and active=1) as prev,
(select top 1 id from test where id>7 and active=1) as next 
from test where id=7--I will use a parameter for 7

Comment: maybe you can use stored procedures to retrieve the previous and next active.

Comment: I want to determine if there will be a next and prev hyperlink for a given student. I can always show the links but I want to prevent extra click if there is no next or prev, then don't show that link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try something like this

```
SELECT  ID,
        Student,
        ( SELECT TOP 1
                    ID
          FROM      dbo.table AS pT
          WHERE     pT.ID < T.ID And Active = 1
          ORDER BY  ID DESC
        ) AS PrevID,
        ( SELECT TOP 1
                    ID
          FROM      dbo.table AS pT
          WHERE     pT.ID > T.ID And Active = 1
          ORDER BY  ID
        ) AS NextID
FROM    dbo.table AS T
```

Answer (score 2):

Working sample

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (id int, student varchar(10), active bit)
insert @t select
1 ,'Bob', 1 union all select
3 ,'Rob', 0 union all select
5 ,'Steve', 1 union all select
7 ,'John', 1 union all select
8 ,'Mark', 0 union all select
10 ,'Dave', 0 union all select
16 ,'Nick', 1

---- your query starts below this line

declare @id int set @id = 5

select id, student,
  isnull((select top(1) Prev.id from @T Prev
   where Prev.id < T.id and Prev.active=1
   order by Prev.id desc),0) Prev,
  isnull((select top(1) Next.id from @T Next
   where Next.id > T.id and Next.active=1
   order by Next.id),0) Next
from @T T
where id = @id
```

The ISNULLs are to return 0 when there is no match - NULL would have worked fine but your question has 0 when there is no `Next`.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at Common Table Expression, a feature for only SQL Server for recursive queries, you can find a link [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927200924/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml)

But this sound like homework, and probebly not the right forum to ask it in.

Regards

Comment: This is not a homework. I saw you tagged. But this is a real problem. I just presented differently to make it simpler to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nested query. I obviously can't test this out, but you should get the idea.

```
SELECT id, student ,
(SELECT C1.id FROM students S1 WHERE S1.active = 1 AND S1.id < S.id LIMIT 1) AS beforeActive, 
(SELECT C2.id FROM categories S2 WHERE S2.active = 1 AND S2.id > S.id LIMIT 1)  AS afterActive
FROM students S
```

Efficiency wise, I've no idea how well this query will perform

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a little more control, especially since you are paginating.

```
WITH NumberedSet AS (
    SELECT  s.id, 
            s.student,
            row_number() OVER (ORDER BY s.id) AS rownum
    FROM    dbo.students AS s
    WHERE   s.active = 1
)
SELECT  cur.id, 
        cur.student, 
        isnull(prv.id,0) AS prev_id, 
        isnull(nxt.id,0) AS next_id
FROM    NumberedSet AS cur
        LEFT JOIN NumberedSet AS prv ON cur.rownum - 1 = prv.rownum
        LEFT JOIN NumberedSet AS nxt ON cur.rownum + 1 = nxt.rownum     
;
```